# NHSREQUEST NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION

Tags: c#

I am attempting to assign string values to `Nsrequest` instance but I'm getting `null reference exception` this is intergration to SAP,ANY HELP?
The class for NHSREquest looks like this

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.6.1080.0")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:com.li.common:objects")]
public class NHSRequest
{
    public NHSRequest();

    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public NHSRequestNHSDetails NHSDetails { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public TechnicalHeader TechnicalHeader { get; set; }
}



NHSRequest locRequest = new NHSRequest();
locRequest.TechnicalHeader.SourceSystem = "Ub";
locRequest.TechnicalHeader.TargetSystem = "DGE0a6";
locRequest.TechnicalHeader.DateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: check your locRequest.TechnicalHeader at runtime it will be null.

Comment: Yes but I am assigning it to locRequest.TechnicalHeader.SourceSystem = "Ub" it should have a value after this but instead it throws null exception from this line

Comment: if 'locRequest.TechnicalHeader' is null, null.SourceSystem can not be accessed and value can not be assigned.

Comment: You need to do locRequest.TechnicalHeader = new TechnicalHeader(){SourceSystem="", TargetSystem = "", DateTime = DateTime.MinValue}

Comment: How do I make it have a value so that I can assign it?

Comment: Thanks a million the error is fixed now.